# center vertical line between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div named `welcome-inputs` and within other two `left` and `right`

The div named `left` needs to be on the left side `welcome-inputs` and the div named `right` right side of `welcome-inputs`.

left and right have width = 100px

Need for a line that is at the MIDDLE of the two, signaling the separation.

view the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/3/

The red line must be in the middle of the images (the images represent left and right)

Comment: Please put your code directly in the question to make it easier for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/gn1asdmh/23/)***

Add a `span` element between `.left` and `.right`

```
<span class="middleLine"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome-inputs {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background:white;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center; /* ADD THIS */
}
.welcomeforms {
    color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px !important;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    /*border-right: 3px solid red; REMOVE THIS */
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
body {
    background:blue;
}

span.middleLine{
   display:inline-block;
   border-right: 2px solid red;
   margin-left:-1px; /* cause the border is 2px */
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/3/)

The other way to resolve it.

```
.left {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

 .right {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position: relative` to `.welcome-inputs`, you can use an `::after` or `::before` pseudo-element on `.left` or `.right` like this:

```
.left::after {
    border-right: 3px solid red;
    content: "";
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc((100% - 3px) / 2); // or use '50%' for better compatibility, but less exactness
}
```

and get rid of the `border-right` on `.left`

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/gn1asdmh/25/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use generated content on the parent element. There is no reason in the given example to use structural markup for this.

Updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/26/

```
.welcome-inputs {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background:white;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
.welcome-inputs::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

.welcomeforms {
    color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px !important;
}


.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

body {
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it would be to use an HTML table.  This will keep it responsive.  Try something like the below code.

```css
.welcome-inputs {
  width: 100%;
}
#leftInput,
#rightInput {
  width: 100px;
}
#separatorInput {
  text-align: center;
}
#dividingLine {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  }
```

```html
<table class="welcome-inputs">
  <tr>
    <td id="leftInput">
      <img width="100%" src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td id="separatorInput"><div id="dividingLine"</td>
    <td id="rightInput">
      <img width="100%" src="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/71832000/jpg/_71832498_71825880.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better: no need to use any empty/dummy elements. We rely on using pseudo-elements instead. In this case I will use `::before`:

```
.welcome-inputs {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background:white;
    height:100px;
    position: relative; /* new property added to original one */
}
.welcome-inputs::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Just remember to declare `position: relative` on the parent element. See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gn1asdmh/28/

p/s: You might want to use vendor prefixes for `transform`, to maximise cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

to add some idea to these answers , you may think as well of :[`box-sizing`](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/27), [`calc()`](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/30/) for instance , or even a simple [`background` image/repeat/sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/29/)